# Double Stub Matching Impedance

Tags: telecommunication, transmission

I'm trying to understand the double stub matching impedance using Smith Chart.

Here is the diagram for the double stub impedance:

[image]

The impedance on the right has to appear purely resistive.
So admittance $Y_2=-jb'$ and admittance $Y_b=1+jb'$
and the admittance at $Y_1$ is elected to be at $3\lambda /8$. Why is this distance chosen to be $3\lambda /8$?
And to get the impedance at this location isn't it enough that I rotate $Y_b$ by $270^0$, why do I have to rotate the whole circle by 270?

Comment: This would be a good question for the [EE stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A trick question? It has only shorted lines. If they are assumed to be lossless the only way to make it resistive is to make its total impedance = zero. I wouldn't call it matching. BTW the whole idea of using double stub is that the placements of the stubs on the line have some room to choose from. A single matching stub must be placed at a certain point and that makes tuning difficult if the load isn't exactly known.